# Codable: Decode a JSONArray to specific fields by index

Tags: swift, swift4, codable

I have this (imho shitty) JSON

```
"geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          6.08235,
          44.62117
        ]
}
```

I wanted to map to this `struct`, dropping the array for 2 fields.

```
struct MMGeometry:Codable {
    let type:String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
}
```

Is the `JSONDecoder` able to do this ? Maybe using a `CodingKey` ?

Comment: You're going to have to either provide a nested type which matches the layout of the JSON that you can then compute these properties from, or just override `init(from: Decoder)` to decode manually.

Answer (score 1):

I went for the *manual* solution :

```
struct Geometry:Codable {
    let type:String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type, coordinates
    }

    enum CoordinatesKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case latitude, longitude
    }

    init (from decoder :Decoder ) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        type = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
        let coords:[Double] = try container.decode([Double].self, forKey: .coordinates)
        if coords.count != 2 { throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: CodingKeys.coordinates, in: container, debugDescription:"Invalid Coordinates") }

        latitude = coords[1]
        longitude = coords[0]
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {

    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, you can throw `DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(...)` which is a slightly nicer convenience method with more debug info.